# How to read data for YUV image using C and disply it on screen

Tags: c

I have to write a `C` code for displaying a YUV image on the screen.
 Can anyone tell the code for this?

Comment: What have you tried, what doesn't work? We really can't write your program for you. You've been pointed at a library that absolute can do the job, and at a site that provides details on YUV and what you have to do to convert it to RGB for display. You seem to be rejecting those answers out of hand. Without some additional clarity, we really can't help you.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, you don't need any conversion between RGB and YUV. In that case it's a simple matter of just displaying the raw data. We can't help you with that without knowing what kind of hardware and/or operating system you use.

Comment: Thnx onemasse for replying. ok i am telling u in detail abt my task. i have to display RGB image through DVSDK DM6467 board on the TV screen but sinve this board doesnt surrort RGB images, we need to convert it to YUV format and then display it.

Comment: and i m working on Linux(ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good primer which discusses some of the color space issues:
http://www.fourcc.org/fccyvrgb.php

Comment: thnx for the reply, but watever link u mentioned , i already checked and in that conversion formulaes are given. I dont reqire this conversion.

Comment: Why not. What makes you think that you can display a YUV image without conversion?

Comment: i have to disaply that image through DVSDK board, and that board doent support display for RGB image

Answer (score 0):

You could try the www.imagemagick.org libraries.

Comment: i dont have to use this library,,,

Comment: hw can i do it in a simple way without using any library??

Comment: Read the samples, convert them from YUV to RGB, and write them to your frame buffer for display. None of these steps are hard, but they do require attention to detail and a library is likely to be the best way to accomplish them.

Comment: ok, i will try watever u mentioned..

Comment: one more thing i need to ask.. i have to display this YUV through DVSDK board which doent support RGB display, wat to do in that case??