# Reading YUV images in C

Tags: c, file, file-format, yuv

1. How to read any yuv image?
2. How can the dimensions of an YUV image be passed for reading to a buffer?

Comment: 1. There are several ways to arrange a YUV image, 444, 420, 422, 420P and 422P and maybe others. Look at this wikipedia site http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YUV

2. I'm not sure what you meen. I don't think there's any standard way of doing that.

Comment: if there is no standard way then what way u can suggest??

Comment: and the link which u mentioned has some conversions formulaes... can u suggest me i a better way how to read yuv image??

Comment: For what environment do you program? What you've tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: m working on linux -ubuntu..basically i have to display Yuv image through DVSDK DM6467. so i am writing a small C program for reading a YUv file and dispalying it on a screen. i got stuck how to read the dimensions of that file to a buffer

Comment: Do you know what exact format you're trying to decode? AFAIK YUV is PIXEL format, not image format. YUV do not give give idea of any image properties other than color information arrangment accross pixels. You have to reveal exact format (e.g. get its MIME type) first.

Comment: This question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4151757/how-to-read-data-for-yuv-image-using-c-and-diaply-it-on-screen .  This is the third time you've asked this question in a month.  If you're not getting the answers you want, then perhaps you should add more detail to your question, in particular describe what you've actually tried.  Maybe post the image you're trying to load as well.  So far it just sounds like you're asking for someone do write your code for you.

Answer (score 5):

1. Usually, when people talk about YUV they talk about [YUV 4:2:0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YUV#Y.27UV420p_.28and_Y.27V12_or_YV12.29).  Your reference to *any* YUV image is misleading, because there are a number of different formats, and each is handled differently.  For example, raw YUV 4:2:0 (by convention, files with an extension `.yuv`) doesn't contain any dimension data; whereas `y4m` files typically do.  So you really need to know what sort of image you're dealing with before you start reading it.  For YUV 4:2:0, you just open the file and read the luminance (Y') and chrominance (CbCr) components in that order, keeping in mind the chrominance components have been decimated (quarter size of the luminance components).  After that you typically convert Y'CbCr to RGB so you can display the image.
2. From what I've mentioned above, you simply **can't** determine the dimensions of *any* YUV image.  Often, the dimensions are simply not in the file.  You have to know them up front -- this is why [most](http://media.cs.tsinghua.edu.cn/~taopin/coding/seq.html) [sites](http://media.xiph.org/video/derf/) listing YUV files for download also list their frame dimensions (and for video, the number of frames).  Most YUV files are either CIF (352x288) or QCIF (176x144), although there are some files digitized from analog video that are in the slightly different SIF format.  Read about the different formats [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Format).